# initiate function using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to call two functions automatically when the page loads.
How to do it with jQuery?

Suppose my function is getData();

How do I initiate this via jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    getData();
});
```

See [Introducing $(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29)

```
$(function()
```

is a shorthand for

`$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: okay now i m going to do something with jquery.get method.
i want to show progress bar during response from server?
 how to do that sir?

Comment: not this dear?
 i want to show ant loading gif during the function done his task

Answer (score 0):

JQuery way

$(function(){

```
getData1();//first function

getData2();//second function
```

});

$(document).ready(function(){

```
            getData1();
            getData2();
```

});

javascript way